# Is there any way to import existing security groups using tags in AWS CDK?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying to import existing security groups into my AWS CDK stack.

I'm able to import it by using security group id using the class method

> ec2.SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id

But i want to import by tag name Is there any way to do it like VPC import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point of time this feature is not available. But there is a feature request raised at [CDK GitHub Repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4241).

Kindly have a look to know status of it.